# SQL Filtering on unique events and datetime

Tags: sql-server

I did ask this question before but deleted the post.

Here is my question: I have a table in SQL Server with multiple events in the table, I am trying to filter on the events and the datetime between the events on a certain X min.

I need help with T-SQL queries.

What can use use to do the following (any links will be appreciated):
take `event_id` and datetime of device, compare to a list of other `event_id`'s to see if there are any other events withing the last 24 min for that device.

What would work for me? Nested queries? Where clause? CTE?

I have tried 6 queries but not getting the result I need, do I use (max) datetime and then compare on event_ID's?

I know this is not much but any help or links would be appreciated....

On Request (Full Query no changes)
1.

```
SELECT A.[Unit_id]
      ,A.[TransDate]
      ,A.[event_id]
      ,A.[event_msg]
      ,B.[TransDate]
      ,B.[event_id]
      ,B.[event_msg]
FROM
(Select
       A.[Unit_id]
      ,MAX(A.[TransDate]) AS Transdate
      ,A.[event_id]
      ,A.[event_msg]
  FROM [JammingEvents].[dbo].[EventLogExtended] AS A
  WHERE event_id = '345'
  GROUP BY A.[Unit_id]
      ,A.[event_id]
      ,A.[event_msg]
  ) AS A
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
       B.[Unit_id]
      ,MAX(B.[TransDate]) AS Transdate
      ,B.[event_id]
      ,B.[event_msg]
  FROM [JammingEvents].[dbo].[EventLogExtended] AS B
  WHERE B.event_id = '985'
  GROUP BY B.[Unit_id]
      ,B.[event_id]
      ,B.[event_msg]
  ) AS B
  ON
  A.Unit_id = B.Unit_id

  WHERE (B.TransDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE,-24,A.Transdate) AND DATEADD(MINUTE,24,A.Transdate))
```

this works but only if you compare 2 event Id's. the problem is i need to do this on a bulk scale.

2.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

SELECT MAX(ELE.Transdate) AS Transdate
      ,ELE.[Unit_id]
      ,ELE.[event_id]
      ,ELE.[event_msg]
      ,ELE.[Latitude]
      ,ELE.[Longitude]
      ,ELE.[date_ack]
      ,ELE.[user_id_ack]
      ,ELE.[date_closed]
      ,ELE.[user_id_closed]
      ,ELE.[action]
      ,ELE.[EventSeqNo]
      ,ELE.[MsgSeqNo]
      ,ELE.[Speed]
      ,ELE.[Heading]
      ,ELE.[Status1]
      ,ELE.[Status2]
      ,ELE.[GeoLocation]
      ,ELE.[Reg_No]
      ,ELE.[Company]
      ,ELE.[Fleet_Code]
      ,ELE.[IgnStatus]
      ,ELE.[comboActioned] 
FROM
[JammingEvents].[dbo].[EventLogExtended] ELE
INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT 
       F.Transdate      ,F.[Unit_id]      ,F.[event_id]      ,F.[event_msg]      ,F.[Latitude]      ,F.[Longitude]      ,F.[date_ack]      ,F.[user_id_ack]
      ,F.[date_closed]      ,F.[user_id_closed]      ,F.[action]      ,F.[EventSeqNo]      ,F.[MsgSeqNo]      ,F.[Speed]      ,F.[Heading]      ,F.[Status1]
      ,F.[Status2]      ,F.[GeoLocation]      ,F.[Reg_No]      ,F.[Company]      ,F.[Fleet_Code]      ,F.[IgnStatus]      ,F.[comboActioned] 
FROM [JammingEvents].[dbo].[EventLogExtended] AS F 
WHERE 
F.event_id IN
('302'
,'303'
,'304'
,'305'
,'309'
,'340'
,'341'
,'345'
,'962'
,'963'
,'973'
,'974'
,'975'
,'976'
,'985'
,'987'
,'989'
,'C220'
,'C222'
,'C224'
,'C227'
,'C228') 
      ) AS A
      ON
      ELE.Unit_id = A.Unit_id
  INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT 
       G.Transdate      ,G.[Unit_id]      ,G.[event_id]      ,G.[event_msg]      ,G.[Latitude]      ,G.[Longitude]      ,G.[date_ack]
      ,G.[user_id_ack]      ,G.[date_closed]      ,G.[user_id_closed]      ,G.[action]      ,G.[EventSeqNo]      ,G.[MsgSeqNo]      ,G.[Speed]      ,G.[Heading]
      ,G.[Status1]      ,G.[Status2]      ,G.[GeoLocation]      ,G.[Reg_No]      ,G.[Company]      ,G.[Fleet_Code]      ,G.[IgnStatus]      ,G.[comboActioned]  
FROM [JammingEvents].[dbo].[EventLogExtended] AS G 
WHERE 
G.event_id = '345'
      ) AS B
  ON
  A.Unit_id = B.Unit_id

  WHERE (ELE.TransDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE,-24,A.Transdate) AND DATEADD(MINUTE,24,A.Transdate))
  AND
  (ELE.event_id IN
  (
  '302'
,'303'
,'304'
,'305'
,'309'
,'340'
,'341'
,'345'
,'962'
,'963'
,'973'
,'974'
,'975'
,'976'
,'985'
,'987'
,'989'
,'C220'
,'C222'
,'C224'
,'C227'
,'C228'
  ))
  AND
  (ELE.action = '0')
  GROUP BY ELE.TransDate
      ,A.Unit_id
      ,ELE.[Unit_id]
      ,ELE.[event_id]
      ,ELE.[event_msg]
      ,ELE.[Latitude]
      ,ELE.[Longitude]
      ,ELE.[date_ack]
      ,ELE.[user_id_ack]
      ,ELE.[date_closed]
      ,ELE.[user_id_closed]
      ,ELE.[action]
      ,ELE.[EventSeqNo]
      ,ELE.[MsgSeqNo]
      ,ELE.[Speed]
      ,ELE.[Heading]
      ,ELE.[Status1]
      ,ELE.[Status2]
      ,ELE.[GeoLocation]
      ,ELE.[Reg_No]
      ,ELE.[Company]
      ,ELE.[Fleet_Code]
      ,ELE.[IgnStatus]
      ,ELE.[comboActioned] 
  ORDER BY ELE.TransDate, ELE.Unit_id DESC
```

so far this got me the closest but i have no idea what to do, i am very poor with SQL syntax and writing queries.

Comment: Can you at least show the queries that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `exists` subquery to demand that there was another event for the same device within the preceeding 24 minutes:

```
select  *
from    Events e1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Events e2
        where   e2.Device_ID = e1.Device_ID
                and e2.event_dt between 
                     dateadd(minute, e1.event_dt, -24)
                     and e1.event_dt
        )
```

Comment: I don't what to use triggers the data coming is large quantity i did try it but it caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

Self join should work as well:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(minute,b.transdate,a.transdate) diff FROM EventLogWxtended a
JOIN eventLogExtended b
ON (a.unit_id=b.unit_id AND b.transdate<a.transdate 
AND DATEDIFF(minute,b.transdate,a.transdate)<24)
```